# Alloy - Get empty set when removing object

Tags: alloy

Consider the following specification in Alloy:

```
sig Books {}
fun f[b:Books] : Books {

    {b':Books | b' = Books -b }
}
run show {}
```

Suppose we have got an instance for which $univ = {Books$0, Books$1, Books$2}$. Evaluating function f with $Books$0$ yields the empty set instead of ${Books$1, Books$2}$:

```
f[Books$0]
{}
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of the way set comprehension works.

```
{b':Books | b' = Books - b }
```

This expression delivers all the *singleton* subsets of `Books` which are equal to `Books - b`. But `Books - b` is a two-element set. So no singleton set is equal to it and the overall result is `{}`.

You probably simply want:

```
fun f[b:Books] : Books {
   Books - b
}
```